# Выбор значка для кнопки "Очистить поле"

Tags: дизайн

Раньше наши редакторы связанных объектов выглядели так:

[image: Выпадающий список]

Функции кнопок:

- Стрелка вниз - открыть выпадающий грид, в котором можно найти запись и выбрать её
- Многоточие - открыть карточку выбранной записи для редактирования
- Плюсик - добавить новую запись в список, отображаемый в выпадающем гриде
- Крестик - очистить поле.

Руководитель высказал вполне здравую мысль, что крестик принято использовать для действия "удалить" или "закрыть", и последний значок следует поменять.

Теперь наши редакторы выглядят вот так:

[image: Новый редактор]

Общий тон кнопок зависит от используемого скина, многоточие и плюсик отсутствуют в связи с семантикой более новой программы, смотреть на две тёмно-синие полоски.

Я-то знаю, что имеется в виду ластик. Но, на мой вкус, выглядит это ужасно, а кроме того, ненаглядно. Всё остальное изображается символами, и только это - неразборчивой картинкой.

Я бы хотел заменить этот значок чем-нибудь поприличнее. У кого-нибудь есть предложения?

Comment: [Вот ластик](http://zavu.ru/Ccdc8rp/), нарисуйте такой же.

Comment: Если его сделать таким, чтобы он влез на эту малюсенькую кнопку, будет так же ненаглядно.

Comment: я показал, что ластик состоит из двух цветов - серого и белого, по крайней мере, в мою юность именно так они и выглядели. Если вы умелый дизайнер, вы, сделая его малюсеньким, сможете воссоздать оригинальное сходство.

Comment: А я подумал, что это не ластик, а карандаш, то есть "Редактировать".

Comment: Вот и я об этом.

Comment: «... крестик принято использовать для действия "удалить" или "закрыть", и последний значок следует поменять» — можно, как контраргумент, вспомнить продукцию Apple (OS X, iOS), там крестики очищают (удаляют текст) текстовое поле. Правда там минимализм и кроме крестиков ничего нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Три варианта, быстро нашедшиеся на «clear icon»:

- [Символ очистки поля](http://www.iconfinder.com/icondetails/9220/16/clear_left_icon). Крестик, правда, но не простой. Символ достаточно частовстречаемый. Учитывая, что универсально понимаемых символов не существует — все равно придется объяснять все в документации и текстовых подсказках.
- [Чистое поле ввода с курсором](http://www.iconfinder.com/icondetails/9255/16/clear_edit_field_icon). Как вариант — должно быть вполне понятно, и нормально видно на мелких размерах. Но могут перепутать с «редактированием» (впрочем, см. факт о несуществовании универсально понимаемых пиктограмм).
- [Метелка](http://www.iconfinder.com/icondetails/38988/16/clear_edit_sweep_sweeper_icon). По мне так не очень, на маленьких размерах выглядит плохо, хотя и субъективно — узнаваемее ластика. Ну и рисунок, а не символ.

Все три конкретно приведенных под GNU GPL, так что, возможно, взять готовое не выйдет, но нарисовать свое по мотивам можно всегда.

Comment: Решили остановиться на варианте "Крестик со стрелочкой", только цвета инвертировать.

Answer (score 2):

Кнопка с [буквой C](http://feenords.ru/uploads/calc.png)?)

Имхо, интуитивно. В терминалах оплаты это стандарт, в калькуляторах, телефонах старых.

Можно ее еще независимо от скина сделать красной, (бледной, чтоб особо не конфликтовала).

Answer (score 0):

Может стоит использовать иконку "возобновить"? Тоесть стрелки типа [image: 1]

. Обычно под возобновлением поля подразумевают именно его очистку.

Comment: Если этот редактор находится на карточке документа, уже существующего в БД, то "возобновить" логичнее трактовать как "сбросить сделанные пользователем изменения", т.е. вернуть полю значение, которое было у последней сохранённой версии документа.